# Terminology: sharpness of upper and lower bounds

Tags: inequality, reference-request, terminology

I'm looking for some mathematical terminology. Suppose you have a function $f(x)$ from and to the real numbers. $U$ and $L$ are upper and lower bounds if $L(x) \le f(x) \le U(x)$, of course. But you can also find a function $u(x)$ such that, for any $N$, there is some $x > N$ with $f(x) \ge u(x)$ and likewise a function $\ell(x)$ such that, for any $N$, there is some $x > N$ with $f(x) \le \ell(x)$. (If $U(x) = u(x)$ then it is said that the upper bound is *sharp*, and likewise for the lower bound.) Is there an established name for $u(x)$ and $\ell(x)$?

Comment: One way to express this in standard terminology would be $\limsup_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-u(x))\ge0$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-\ell(x))\le0$, but I guess that's not a name for $u(x)$ and $\ell(x)$.

Comment: @joriki Right. I'm looking for a more convenient or conventional way to express ideas like "a(n) is at most tetrational, but is known i.o. to be at least cubic".